# XSL FO style text in a note

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I am trying to style the p element in following code using xsl fo

```
<note>
<p>Le numéro identifiant est une chaîne de caractères composée des éléments suivants: 
<ul>
<li>une chaîne de caractères fixe correspondant à l'acronyme du module, sur cinq positions,</li>
<li>un numéro séquentiel incrémenté d’une unité à chaque création de dossier.</li>
</ul>
</p>
</note>
```

With following XSl the red color stops at first ul and does not apply to the whole p element

```
<xsl:attribute-set name="ul.li__content">
    <xsl:attribute name="color">red</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:attribute-set>
```

Adding another p element to contain ul does not work.

Adding a p element in li omits the dash before the li element.

How would you manage this issue? Should I change the xsl to use attributes?

Thanks, best regards.

Comment: We'll need to see more of your XSL to be able to help. There should be a template match="note" and/or template match="p" which can both influence what the note will look like.

Comment: @Hobbes is correct and also, if you think that CSS style identifiers are the same in XSL FO you are mistaken. You cannot write something in XSL FO like "ul > li > p" to indicate come CSS structure, it does not work that way.

Comment: There should be a command `xsl:use-attribute-sets` that calls the `xsl:attribute-set` you mentioned. The code around this command is crucial: that will tell you where the attribute-set will be applied.